# Get parse_query filter to return slug instead of id

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin, query, parse

After much headache in the last week I feel like my problem is almost solved. I have been attempting to customize the admin edit.php page of custom post types to display and sort/filter custom taxonomies. I've frankensteined a collection of actions and filters from things found on the web but fear I may be using deprecated code as some of them were quite old.

I think I've narrowed the problem down to this filter

```
add_filter('parse_query','convert_large_feature_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query');
function convert_large_feature_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;
    if ($pagenow=='edit.php' &&
            isset($qv['taxonomy']) && $qv['taxonomy']=='large_feature' &&
            isset($qv['term']) && is_numeric($qv['term'])) {
        $term = get_term_by('id',$qv['term'],'large_feature');
        $qv['term'] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```

When I choose the dropdown menu for `large_feature` it accurately displays the "categories" (is that what you call them when they are of a custom taxonomy?) and post count, however when it is actually filtered, the query comes up empty. I noticed, however, that when I modified the query URL from

```
http://www.ampeg.com/2012/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=all&post_type=ampeg_artists&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&large_feature=291&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
```

to

```
http://www.ampeg.com/2012/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=all&post_type=ampeg_artists&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&large_feature=home_page_large&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
```

It displays as intended.

This leads me to believe that this filter isn't outputting the slug as it's supposed to... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`taxonomy` & `term` won't be set (in this case), since query vars are mapped from GET/POST.

In other words, `$qv['large_feature'] = 291` (see [`wp_edit_posts_query()`](http://wpseek.com/wp_edit_posts_query/) and `WP_Query::get_posts()` for the big picture).

```
add_filter( 'parse_query','convert_large_feature_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query' );

function convert_large_feature_id_to_taxonomy_term_in_query( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;

    $qv =& $query->query_vars;

    if (
        $pagenow == 'edit.php' &&
        isset( $qv['large_feature'] ) &&
        ctype_digit( $qv['large_feature'] ) // stricter than is_numeric()
    ) {
        if ( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $qv['large_feature'], 'large_feature' ) )
            $qv['large_feature'] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```